# g++ typedef templates in inheritor class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typedef

simplifying my problem we can consider:

```
template <class T>
class Base{
    typedef typename std::pair<T, T> pair;
};

template <class T>
class Inheritor : public Base<T> {
    pair *p;                          
    // mean that we want to use constructor of std::pair.
    // say: std::pair withou argument list

    Inheritor<T>::pair *p;
    // dont see his typename
    // say: pair does not name a type

    typename pair *p;
    // I was sure that it works.
    // I dont know why it doesnt work.
    // say: expected nested-name-specifier before 'pair

    typename Inheritor<T>::pair *p;
    // ok!
};
```

why we cant write typename pair *p ? I dont understand reasons of Inheritor:: ! it make code more complex and bad to read!

PS
(of cource public. as I say "simplifying my problem...")

```
typedef typename Base<T>::pair pair;
```

In my mind it is a ... russian word that is hard to translate [("костыль")](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/talks/3588892)

It look like Kludge or duct tape or hack =)

As I understand:

typedefs inherit as usual function or variable.
but it is not accessible (!!!).
to acess it we should write

```
typedef typename Base<T>::pair pair;
```

or

```
typedef typename Inheritor<T>::pair pair;
```

it looks like funny [Hindu code](http://lurkmore.ru/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) but we needs it! (>_<)''''

of cource in public scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a type name depends on a template parameter, it is a *dependent name*. [You have to use `typename` to indicate you're naming a type.](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) Read that article, and you'll see your use of `typename` doesn't make sense, except in the last case.

Here's how your code should probably look:

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
public: // you probably don't want a private typedef
    typedef std::pair<T, T> pair; // typename isn't needed here, this isn't dependent
};

template <class T>
class Inheritor : public Base<T>
{
public: // public again
    typedef typename Base<T>::pair pair; // get the Base's pair type, typedef it

    pair *p; // ah, easy to use
};
```